# delaying a render of index until initialization is complete

Tags: backbone.js

I'm wondering why the attempt to render the index function is giving me a `cannot call method render of null` error. Is there a way to make the index function wait to render until the initialization of the router is complete. The console.logs seem to suggest that the index function is trying to render before the ajax call in the initialization is done

```
1.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'render' of null gallery.js:231
2. XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/readjsonfile". jquery.js:8241
3.success
```

This is the code. I have a route

```
var Gallery = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes: {
        "": "index",

    },
```

It is initally set to null

```
 _index: null,
```

The initialization of the Gallery router checks if the index is null, and, if it is, creates a new view with data.

```
initialize: function(options) {

        var ws = this;

        if (this._index === null){
            $.ajax({

                url: 'galleries',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {},
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("success");
                    console.log(data);
                    ws._data = data;
                    ws._photos = new PhotoCollection(data);
                    ws._index = new IndexView({model: ws._photos});
                    console.log(ws._index);

                    Backbone.history.loadUrl();

                }, 
                error: function(r){
                    console.log("error");
                    console.log(r);
                }
            });
            return this;
        }
        return this;
    },
```

This is the index function, placed immediately after the initialization,  that renders the view created in the initialization above, however, I'm getting a `Cannot call method 'render' of null` error

```
index: function() {

        this._index.render();
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XHR requests are asynchronous by default, which means that your `$.ajax` call won't block and your initial route will be immediately matched, `_index` is not yet defined at that point and you get an error.

If your code looks like this,

```
var r = new Gallery();
Backbone.history.start();
```

what happens is

1. `router.initialize` is called
2. a XHR request is emitted
3. `router.initialize` ends
4. `Backbone.history.start` triggers an *index* route
5. `router.index` is called
6. the XHR request concludes

Check this Fiddle to reproduce your problem http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/krFtA/

Some things you can do:

- if possible, [bootstrap models in your page load](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap), that will save you a request and some headaches,
- force a synchronous request with `async: false` that will block until your data is available (basically, what you had in mind, I think) :

  ```
  $.ajax({
      async: false,
      url: 'galleries',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {},
      success: function(data) {
          ...
      }, 
      error: function(r){
          ...
      }
  })
  ```

  http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/m3dW5/
- as @fencliff said, delay `Backbone.history.start` until you are ready.
- or with jQuery >= 1.5, you could use a [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to synchronize your request and your rendering

  ```
  var PhotoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      url: 'galleries',

      initialize: function() {
          this.loaded = $.Deferred();
      },

      fetch: function(opts) {
          var ld = this.loaded,
              xhr = Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, opts);
          xhr.always(ld.resolve);
      }
  });

  var IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '#v',
      initialize: function() {
          _.bindAll(this);
      },
      render: function() {
          this.$el.html('rendered');
          console.log('render');
      }
  });

  var Gallery = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
          "": "index"
      },

      _index: null,

      initialize: function(options) {
          this._photos = new PhotoCollection();
          this._photos.fetch();
          this._index = new IndexView({model: this._photos});
          console.log(this._index);
      },

      index: function() {
          var view = this._index;
          view.model.loaded.always(view.render);
      }
  });
  ```

  http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/m3dW5/1/

Comment: This is an awesome answer. i'm going to play around with it to make sure I can get it to work and understand it all, and come back to accept later. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`Backbone.history.start` triggers a route that matches the current URL, so you need to delay calling it until your routers are ready.

So instead of calling `loadUrl` in the `$.ajax` success callback, wait until your dependencies are loaded and call history.start instead:

```
success: function(data) {
    //...
    Backbone.history.start();
}
```